# MySQL complex join for multiple inclusion and exclusion

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I've got a client that wants me to make a tagging system. I've got three tables: `items`, `tags`, and `item_tag_assoc` - the last one only serves to associate item_ids and tag_ids. Here's the problem I'm having:

If the user requests included tags [1, 2, 3] and excluded tags [4, 5, 6], the result should be all items that have **EVERY** tag in [1, 2, 3] (not just one) and **NO** tags in [4, 5, 6]. How do I write a query to accomplish this?

I researched enough to figure out inner joins for the tag inclusion:

`SELECT i.item_id, i.item_title FROM items AS i INNER JOIN tag_item_assoc AS tia1 ON (tia1.item_id = i.item_id AND tia1.tag_id = 1)`

...and just chain on the same inner join pattern for as many tags as you want to include. It may be a little bulky, but users won't be choosing more than 4 or 5 tags before they move on, so it'll do.

I was really hoping that I could exclude the same way, and wrap everything into one query:

`INNER JOIN tag_item_assoc AS tia2 ON (tia2.item_id = i.item_id AND tia2.tag_id!= 2)`

But it became obvious very quickly that wasn't going to work. I read a couple of articles that said `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s could let me exclude while I include, but I couldn't figure them out, mostly because of the stray `WHERE` clauses. Any permutation of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s and `INNER JOIN`s I tried either yielded an error or very confusing results.

All that to say - does anyone here know how I can accomplish this? I apologize for not having any useful code examples to provide. I'm ok with starting from scratch if the `INNER JOIN`s are an obstacle - I just need a way to accomplish multiple association inclusion and exclusion at the same time. Thanks in advance for the help and expertise!

Comment: could be as simple as  where tags IN ( 1, 2, 3)

Comment: Not quite - IN(1, 2, 3) would match items with tags [1], [1, 3], etc. I need to find only items with EVERY tag in the set [1, 2, 3]. Thanks for the response, hope this clarifies!

Comment: It will be helpful if can you provide sample data and sample output for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Instead of adding `INNER JOIN`s like so:

`INNER JOIN tag_item_assoc AS tia2 ON (tia2.item_id = i.item_id AND tia2.tag_id!= 2)`

I added a sub-query with a single inner join:

`WHERE i.item_id NOT IN ( SELECT i.item_id FROM items AS s INNER JOIN tag_item_assoc AS tia1 ON (tia1.item_id = i.item_id AND tia1.tag_id IN (4, 5, 6)))`

The sub-query creates a set of all `item`s that have any of the tags in [4, 5, 6], and `WHERE i.iten_id NOT IN` eliminates any records that match that set.

Thanks everyone for the effort! Hopefully this will help someone down the road.

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the number of instances of records to the number of your tags:

```
SELECT a.item_id -- , add other columns here
FROM   items a
          INNER JOIN item_tag_assoc b
             ON a.item_id = b.item_id
WHERE b.tag_id IN (1, 2, 3) AND
      b.tag_id NOT IN (4, 5, 6)
GROUP BY a.item_id
HAVING COUNT(a.item_id) = 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's much more elegant than the solution I came up with. Is there a way to exclude tags with a similar method?

Comment: Not exactly - the (1, 2, 3) works fine, but the (4, 5, 6) portion seems wrong to me. Aren't we just including the set we're trying to exclude?

Comment: oh sorry. i see it now, it should be `NOT IN`. Can you try it again @CodeMoose? Hope it works now..

Comment: For some reason it's not accepting any tags now - all queries return empty results.

Comment: try changing `AND` to `OR` @CodeMoose

Comment: Still not quite there. Item A has tags 1, 2, and 3 - when I search for items with tags 1, 2, and 4, item A still shows up

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM items a
     INNER JOIN item_tag_assoc b
         ON a.item_id = b.item_id
     INNER JOIN tags c
         ON a.tag_id = c.tag_id
WHERE c.tag_id IN(1) AND
      c.tag_id IN(2) AND
      c.tag_id IN(3) AND
      c.tag_id NOT IN (4) AND
      c.tag_id NOT IN (5) AND
      c.tag_id NOT IN (6) ;
```

Comment: I did - still not quite what I'm looking for. Thanks for the effort though!